# Create custom activity indicator in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I haven't found any references to apps that use a custom activity indicator -- would be an animated GIF old-school -- in place of the Apple-supplied spinning wheels. Are there facilities to do this (or subclass UIActivityIndicatorView), do developers roll their own UIViews, or does this violate HIG?

Thanks, IPD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, as Ed Marty mentioned UIImageView supports the animation of images. So look at this [custom activity indicator](http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/custom-activity-indicator) tutorial to get an inspiration how you could achieve this in a very simple way.

Cheers

Comment: Perfect... that's exactly what I was looking for in my app!

Answer (score 2):

The UIImageView class supports animation.  Try that.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use an animation to rotate the layer.
Here is an interesting post about how to do that :

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/10/25/core-animation-tutorial-slider-based-layer-rotation/

Hope this helps.

Thierry

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a simple rotation effect. I as just wondering if this is the kind of thing that other apps do -- there isn't much to override by subclassing UIAnimation.