# How to create a custom Activity Indicator in Xcode

Tags: iphone

i need a know how to create a custom activity Indicator in xcode, i tired of searching in websites, i didn find anything about it.Please help meee...

Comment: You can also check this [link](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=336) for custom activity indicator.

Comment: may be a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812832/create-custom-activity-indicator-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 12):

The activity indicator is just an image view with an image sequence animation. To make your own make still pictures of each frame of your activity indicator animation and use code like this:

```
UIImageView *customActivityIndicator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];

customActivityIndicator.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"],[etc...],[etc...],nil];
customActivityIndicator.animationDuration = 1.0; // in seconds
customActivityIndicator.animationRepeatCount = 0; // sets to loop

[customActivityIndicator startAnimating]; // starts animating
[customActivityIndicator stopAnimating]; //stops animating
```

Comment: thanks for ur rply Thomas clayson

Answer (score -3):

What are you calling custom activity Indicator ? it could be just an icon...

Comment: an activity indicator is a ui object - UIActivityIndicatorView - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html

Comment: I know that... but Chinju talk about custom indicator...

Comment: thanks Benoit for ur ur rply...